# Date formate in spanish not working in ubuntu

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am using below code for convert date into spanish in window system

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'spanish_spain')
```

For ubuntu i am trying below code but its not working on ubuntu

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'es-es')
```

can you please suggest how to deal with spanish language.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo locale-gen es_ES.UTF-8

This command is solution for my Question.

Thanks